# Java Cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, for-loop

Writing a for loop in a neural network i'm working on, and it's throwing an error for part of the loop condition itself.

The code is as follows:

```
// for each neuron sum the (inputs * corresponding weights) .Throw
// the total at our sigmoid function to get the output.

for (int j = 0; j < neuronLayers.get(i).numNeurons; ++j)
    {}
}
```

neuronLayers itself is an ArrayList, defined as such:

```
// storage for each layer of neurons including the output layer

private ArrayList<Double> neuronLayers;
```

and numNeurons is an integer value from another class, SNeuronLayer, defined as such:

```
// the number of neurons in this layer

int numNeurons;
```

The error is with

```
neuronLayers.get(i).numNeurons;
```

and it says "numNeurons cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as i'm going to have to reference another ArrayList from the same second class in the for loop itself and i'd like to know how best to phrase it to ensure my code works.

Comment: Well yes, `neuronLayers.get(i)` will be a `Double`, not a `SNeuronLayer`.

Comment: Is that a typo or a you really having a loop with an empty body (`{}`)?

Comment: I'm not going to have a loop with an empty body, I just haven't written the body out yet because looking through it i'm going to have the same issue with some of the code i'm putting in the body of the for loop.

Comment: I suggest you learn about enhanced for loop. This will allow you to loop over your `ArrayList` more easily and simplify all the `neuronLayers.get(i)` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** When you do `neuronLayers.get(i)`, it returns double, so you can not access the `SNeuronLayer`. Instead, Try to make ArrayList of that class and include that double value as one of the attributes. So you can access both `Double` and `SNeuronLayer`.

Let's assume you have class named `SNeuronLayer`. Than keep following attributes in it.

```
class SNeuronLayer{
    int numNeurons;
    double your_double;
}
```

now define array list as:

```
ArrayList<SNeuronLayer> list;
```

So you can access double value by

```
list.get(i).your_double;
```

and you can access Int value like:

```
list.get(i).numNeurons;
```

Comment: Hey, this explains the logic quite well. Would you be able to give me an example of how i'd write it?

Comment: @JosephOliver `ArrayList<SNeuronLayer>`.

Comment: ah thank you! Would I declare this at the start of the class i'm working in, or the method?